# local storage - save javascript function state and timer when browser closed

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I have a javascript function that changes image `onclick` and sets a timer for a new image to appear, but I need to save it in the `localStorage` if the browser gets refreshed or closes unexpectedly.

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
    function aktivereSkift() {
        $(this).attr("src", "/lib/pictures/1.png")
        
        setTimeout(() => $(this).attr('src', '/lib/pictures/2.png'), 5000);         
    }

    $(".toilet").on("click", aktivereSkift)
});
```

I need to save the state both without clicked and if clicked and also save the amount of time passed in the timer, so it will be the same when the page is opened again.

Comment: on refresh you ca use [beforeunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/beforeunload_event), on unexpected crash you can do  nothing

Comment: thank i will look into beforeunload

Comment: Why not save the state everytime an action is performed, e.g. on click or image load and check against that date everytime you load the page.

Comment: Im no sure how i can achive this, is it possible u can make an example for me? thank u in advance

Answer (score -2, accepted):

In the following code example you can see how to extend your code to use local storage to save and load the parameters you need. I have added comments to the code to explain how each part works.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  function aktivereSkift(initImagePath=null, initNextImagePath=null, count=5) {
    // if the image paths are undefined stop executing
    if (initImagePath === null || initNextImagePath === null) {
      return false;
    }
    $(this).attr("src", initImagePath);
    // your timer will be the count * 1000
    let timer = count*1000;
    let counter = setInterval(timer, 1000);
    function timer() {
      count = count-1;
      // every time a second passes the current count is stored in the localstorage
      localStorage.setItem('counter', count);
      if (count <= 0) {
         clearInterval(counter);
         return;
      }
    }
    setTimeout(() => $(this).attr('src', initNextImagePath), timer);
    // store the current image path
    localStorage.setItem('imagepath', initImagePath);

    // store the next image path
    localStorage.setItem('nextimagepath', initNextImagePath);
  }
  
  // handle initial load
  function loadDefaultValues() {
    // load the stored value for the initial image from localstorage
    const initImagePath = localStorage.getItem('imagepath');
    // load the stored value for the next image from localstorage
    const initNextImagePath = localStorage.getItem('nextimagepath');
    // load remaining counter
    const counter = localStorage.getItem('counter');
    
    // continue from where you left of
    aktivereSkift(initImagePath, initNextImagePath, counter);
  }

  // execute initial load function 
  loadDefaultValues();  
  
  $(".toilet").on("click", () => {
    // don't forget to pass the image paths as parameters
    aktivereSkift('/lib/pictures/toiletBegyndt.png', '/lib/pictures/toiletSlut.png');
  });
});
```

Comment: I can't find timing save and reinit

Comment: Hmm, I thought based on the code that the issue was to save the image to show, not the timer. Let me update my answer

Comment: Thank you stavros, but where should i declare the variables to hold teh initimagepath and initnextimagepath, at this moment when i click on the button nothing happens?

Comment: The `initimagepath` and `initnextimagepath` are loaded in the `$(".toilet").on("click", () =>` function the first time and on reload from the browser's localstorage. Every time you want to update them you need to call the `aktivereSkift` function with the new paths as parameters. If nothing happens when you click the button check 1. that the paths are correct, 2. extend the `aktivereSkift` function to select your html elements and update their `src` attribute with the new values.